# Wrap a DataGrid in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, datatable, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid that is being populated by a DataTable. Problem is that the DataTable has 12 columns but only 9 will show in the DataGrid as thats all that will fit on the page.

Anyone know how to wrap a DataGrid so the rest of the columns show further down the page? or any other ideas of how I could solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can put the DataGrid into a ScrollViewer.  Then you could see all 12 columns via a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately a scrollviewer won't really work for me as I need to print it after it is generated and I need all columns in the view

Comment: Could just turn your DataGrid into something like an ItemsControl with what were originally your Columns styled and formatted however you want as an ItemTemplate

Comment: Could you please explain how you are printing?  I just tried Printing the `DataGrid` in my answer, and it outputted the entire `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to wrap a data grid object instead you could put the DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer and enable the HorizontalScroll.

ScrollViewer Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to wrap it easily.  I guess you would have to manage which columns are displayed by monitoring the width of your controls (not to mention having multiple data tables).  Yuck!  I'd suggest going with inserting your `DataGrid` inside of a `ScrollViewer`  This will be consistent with many other user interfaces as well, allowing your application to be more easily understood.

Just make sure to set the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property to `Auto` or `Visible`

See XAML below:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 4" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 5" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 6" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 7" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 8" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 9" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 10" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This creates the `DataGrid` below:

[image: Scrolling Datagrid]

**EDIT:**
Since you need to print the `DataGrid`, I'll post a snippet on how to print it.  This will print the entire `DataGrid`; however, if your `DataGrid` is indeed too large, then you may need to look at modifying the output image.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    dialog.PrintVisual(dataGrid1, "The Entire DataGrid");
}
```

You can find `PrintDialog` in the namespace: `System.Windows.Controls`
The [`PrintDialog.PrintVisual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual(v=vs.110).aspx) function can be used to print your WPF controls, simply pass the control as the first argument.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your post. The datagrid is exported to a PDF so when it is printed from there is only prints the visible columns

Comment: How large are each of your columns?  I printed the above `DataGrid` to a PDF, but those columns are very small, so it fit well on the page.  If your columns are too large, perhaps you can see about printing to the PDF by rotating the result 90°.  Also, try to find ways you can shrink or separate your data in a meaningful way :) --If you really need to have multiple `DataGrids`, it should be possible, but you would need to look at manipulating which columns appear in which grid in your C# code-behind.